# Noun and verb after "either one or all": singular or plural?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I think it is grammatical to say

1. "Almost every day, either this table or that one **is** reserved."

What about the following sentence?

2. "Almost every day, either one or all **tables are** reserved."

What if we change the places of 'one' and 'all'?

3. "Almost every day, either all or one **table is** reserved."

Comment: I don't understand the context. What possible situation could reduce the possibilities to either ONE table or ALL tables? Why couldn't there be TWO reserved tables, or why couldn't all tables EXCEPT one be reserved? The exact context being asked about here seems so unlikely we can't really say how people would usually express it. Perhaps it just needs a more credible real-world context in which to consider the syntax.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, in a specific piece of software there are a number of *groups*. At each moment either exactly one of them is *active* or all are *active* together. That's the rule of the software. I thought maybe by replacing 'group' with 'chair' and 'be active' with 'be reserved' things can be a little more clear.

Comment: In that context, *either one or all groups are active*. A third possible permutation that might occur in such contexts is *At any given point within program execution, [either] **one, none, or all groups are** active*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact context being asked about here seems so unlikely it's not easy to say how people would usually express it. But the general principle is if there's a "compound subject" ("one table" + "all tables" here) followed by a verb, the verb form agrees with the ***last*** component noun.

If the compound noun contains both singular and plural elements, we usually choose to put a plural element last, because that makes for more natural phrasing. The examples here are all a bit weird, but...

> 1 *Either **this table** or **those tables** ARE reserved* - most natural
> 2 *Either **those tables** or **this table** IS reserved* - less natural
> 3 *Either **those tables** or **this table** ARE reserved* - much less natural
> 4 *Either **this table** or **those tables** IS reserved* - **very unusual**